# SymmetricDS Postgres target gives "Failed to read table" for all sym_* tables

Tags: postgresql, docker, symmetricds

I'm trying to setup a simple replication from MySQL to Postgres. Identical schemas. After following the steps in the [Demo Tutorial](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/tutorials.html#_demo) with a slight change (using MySQL and Postgres drivers) I am still unable to get the replication working.

A few changes were needed based on complaints after running `bin/sym`

1. `SET GLOBAL show_compatibility_56 = ON` needed to be set in the MySQL DB
2. For Postgres I needed to use `protocolVersion=3` instead of 2 which was set in the example.

The weird thing is that SymmetricDS is able to create the `sym_*` tables, but complains about not being able to read them. I have verified that the tables do not exist before `bin/sym` is run, but do exist after. Here is an excerpt from the log

```
// Successful creation of table
[store-001] - PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect - DDL applied: CREATE TABLE "sym_notification"(
    "notification_id" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ("notification_id")
)

...

// Unable to read from created table
[store-001] - PostgreSqlDdlReader - Failed to read table: sym_notification
[store-001] - PostgreSqlDdlReader - Failed to read table: sym_notification
[store-001] - AbstractDatabaseWriter - Did not find the sym_notification table in the target database
[store-001] - PostgreSqlDdlReader - Failed to read table: sym_monitor
[store-001] - PostgreSqlDdlReader - Failed to read table: sym_monitor
[store-001] - AbstractDatabaseWriter - Did not find the sym_monitor table in the target database
```

The same error apply for all the `sym_*` tables.

The databases are running in Docker, but since SymmetricDS is not complaining about being unable to connect, and is able to create the tables, I assume it is not related to Docker.

The database in the Postgres DB is created by the same user as specified in `engines/store-001.properties`. Could this still have something to do with roles and access privileges?

Comment: Any error messages in the Postgres server log?

Comment: Yes, before each STATEMENT it logs, there is an error message: `ERROR:  column am.amcanorder does not exist at character 427` @NickBarnes

Comment: Looks like SymmetricDS doesn't support your version of Postgres. The `pg_am.amcanorder` column was [there in 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-am.html), but was [removed in 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-am.html).

Comment: Wait, is this error coming from the SymmetricDS session? That column name doesn't seem to be mentioned in their codebase. It might be caused by something unrelated.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Replication works using Postgres 9.5.5 instead of 9.6.1 (latest tag on Docker). But the Postgres server log says `ERROR:  relation "gp_id" does not exist at character 20 STATEMENT:  select gpname from gp_id` for all 9.x versions, so I guess this could potentially cause trouble in the future.

Comment: Yes, the error is triggered when I run `bin/sym`, which initiates replication from the MySQL source to the Postgres target.

Comment: The `gp_id` error doesn't look like a problem. Judging by the [source](https://github.com/JumpMind/symmetric-ds/blob/0c5cc1c24b42a64405f4b79c3cb6b594a35467f2/symmetric-jdbc/src/main/java/org/jumpmind/db/platform/greenplum/GreenplumPlatform.java#L31), it's just testing to see if you're running Greenplum (a Postgres fork).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to the latest JDBC driver from Postgres it will work.

Replace the existing Postgres driver from the lib directory from the latest from here:  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: The driver will be updated in 3.8.11.

https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2926

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the postgres database with the same username/password used by symmetric-ds from some DB navigator, for example [Jetbrain's Datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) and then try inserting, updating, selecting something from sym_* tables. Assign access rights to the user if necessary.

Comment: This works fine, so there must be something else that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When using Postgres 9.6.1 (current latest release) the following error is logged on the server when running `bin/sym`

```
ERROR: column am.amcanorder does not exist at character 427
```

The problem was resolved by using Postgres 9.5.5 instead thanks to [Nick Barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104979/nick-barnes) pointing this out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888672/symmetricds-postgres-target-gives-failed-to-read-table-for-all-sym-tables#comment68993024_40888672).